# Expiration of Active Directory accounts

Tags: active-directory, user-accounts, windows-server

Requesting their support if I can guide in order to obtain a list of users that is soon to expire your account on my active directory.

Answer (score 1):

See this great MSDN magazine article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)

In [section 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx#S8), the authors talk about how to query for common things like finding users whose accounts will expire in a given period of time.

By doing something quite simple like this, you can find all users whose account will expire by Dec 15:

```
// establish domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find users whose accounts will expire by Dec 15
PrincipalSearchResult<UserPrincipal> users = 
      UserPrincipal.FindByExpirationTime(ctx, new DateTime(2010, 12, 15), 
                                         MatchType.LessThanOrEquals);
```

Now you have a list of `UserPrincipal` accounts that will expire soon.

Comment: What if I want to filter by BETWEEN two dates.